# Symfony2 FormType add element to entity field (on top)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form whith a entity field like this one :

```
$builder->add('account', 'entity', [
    'label'         => 'account',
    'class'         => Account::class,
    'query_builder' => $accountsQueryBuilder,
    'choice_label'  => 'numberAndName',
]);
```

I want to add an option "All accounts" to this field, I do it like this :

```
public function finishView (FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $new_choice = new ChoiceView(array(), 'all', 'All accounts');
    $view->children['account']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;
}
```

My problem is that the added field is on the bottom of the list. Is there a clean way to put it on the top of the list ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: If you don't use form_widget, you can choose the order of field by call form_row in the order you prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Symfony, so I could be way off here, but from your code `$view->children['account']->vars['choices']` appears to be an array. So you should be able to use `array_unshift` to put a new element on the top.

```
array_unshift($view->children['account']->vars['choices'], $new_choice);
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Make sure you click that up arrow *(shameless self-promotion)*